# If $\forall f \in \mathcal{H}(\Omega)$ such that $f(z)\neq 0$ exists a square root then $\Omega$ is simply connected

Tags: complex-analysis

If $\forall f \in \mathcal{H}(\Omega)$  such that $f(z)\neq 0$ for  all $z\in \Omega$ $\exists$  $\varphi \in \mathcal{H}(\Omega)$ such that $\varphi^2=f$ $\implies$  $\Omega$ is simply connected.

Is there  a "quick" way to do this? Or should I consider a family of functions emulating Riemann's mapping theorem proof?

Comment: Is that the space of holomorphic function on $\Omega$?

Comment: Yes, @John . I thought it was standard notation.

Comment: In my complex analysis course we proved a very long theorem stating exactly what you say, and we called it "another version of the Riemann Mapping Theorem". So I think that a quick way to prove it does not exist yet (however I don't exclude that a quick way could exist).

Comment: @Abellan : Okay. I just want to make sure it is not the space of harmonic function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt at a proof ($\Omega$ assumed connected of course)

Assume that $\Omega$ is not simply connected. There exists a Jordan curve $\gamma$ (a polygonal one if needed ) in $\Omega$ that contains inside a point $a$ not in $\Omega$ ( this should be obvious and is not that hard to prove). The function $z-a$ cannot have a root in $\mathcal{H}(\Omega)$.

Comment: Why $z-a$ cannot have a root?

Comment: @Abellan: I would first prove that $z$ has not root in $\mathcal{H}(\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\})$. Can you prove that?